# Display Javascript "same origin policy" violations

Tags: javascript, firefox, firebug, xss, same-origin-policy

I'm developing a mobile app which runs a simple HTTP server and a WebView. The WebView displays an external website which should access the server via javascript (GET). Unfortunately this doesn't work and I assume it's due to the same origin policy but the console doesn't show any errors. I had a similar error before which required me to define "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" on the server side. This error already took a while to find because there were no error messages (Firebug "Net" tab showed a completed GET request with empty "response" data). Now I assume a same origin policy violation in the external script, but it's hard to tell because of the missing error messages. The only "hint" I see is in Firebug "Net" tab, showing a connection which "never completes". I checked the packages sent to localhost but there wasn't even a connection attempt => thus I assume the browser is holding it back.

How do I display Javascript "same origin policy" violation errors in Firefox (ext: Firebug, Webdeveloper)?

Comment: Which mobile platform is this? When you say the app "runs a simple HTTP server" you mean the server is running on the phone?

Answer (score 0):

Firefox(3.6.20 and Chrome) throws an error on XMLHttpRequest cross domain violations. These errors can being silenced by `try{...} catch(ignore){}` blocks. If you know the actual path of the request you can check in the Firebug's "Net" tab, all the requests(even those denied by  "same origin policy") show in the "All" section, and in the "XHR" section those denied by  "same origin policy" don't.

Comment: I only see connections which never complete, but no hint about (possibly) violating the same origin policy. It'd be nice if the browser would tell me something like "I'm not finishing this connection because of the same origin policy". I check the packages sent on localhost and there isn't even a connection attempt, thus I *assume* the browser is holding it back.